# Run python script right after RPi boot

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm relatively new to raspberry pi (5 days using it) and I've just finished to run my python script succesfully (called dogcare.py). Now I'm trying to execute this script right after my raspberry is turned on. I've been doing some research and I find different ways to do it:

- using /etc/profile
- using /etc/rc.local
- using crontab
- using /etc/init.d
- using systemd

But none of these ways are working for me.

**Setup enviroment:**
Hardware: RaspberryPi 2 Model B
Software: Raspbian or NOOBs (not sure)

**Context:**
Since for my project I need to run meet.jit.si, I followed this guide http://www.instructables.com/id/Video-Calling-on-Raspberry-Pi-3/?ALLSTEPS and It has a step where sets chromium website to start right after RPi is turned on. (Currently this is working fine)

My python script is using request library in order to use HTTP GET with an external website application I've been working on.

**Main problem:**

I need to run both events: chromium website with meet.jit.si and my python script when my raspberry is turned on.
Current situation: chromium website is running after my RPi is turned on but my script doesn't.

I'd appreciate any help !

Comment: You claim none of those listed files work, but you haven't said what you tried to put into them. Giving the full path to the script in rc.local should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing with my Raspi 2 as well which involved sending myself an email with the ip address of the pi so I could easily ssh/vnc to it.

My steps involved making a shell script which ran the python program.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd pythonfiledirectory
sudo python pythonfile.py
cd /
```

Then I made it executable with the following command:

```
chmod 777 file.sh
```

Now edit your crontab to run the file on startup.

In your terminal, type:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Inside of the crontab write:

```
@reboot sh file.sh
```

You could add a log file if you wanted to debug and see why it's not working by making a log directory and changing the text you wrote in the crontab to:

```
@reboot sh file.sh >/logdirectoy/ 2>&1
```

This is what made it work for me and if it doesn't work try and make sure you can run your .sh file and try the crontab with some other files to debug the problem.